# Comparing two text files with each other

Tags: linux, windows, command-line

If I had to text files, for example:

file1.txt

```
apple
orange
pear
banana
```

file2.txt

```
banana
pear
```

How would I take all phrases on the lines of file2.txt away from file1.txt

So file1.txt would be left with:

```
apple
orange
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
combine file1 not file2
```

On Debian and derivatives, combine can be found in the moreutils package.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -v -F -f file2.txt file1.txt
```

-v means listing only the lines of file1.txt that do not match the pattern, and -f  means taking the patterns from the file, in this case — file2.txt. And -F — interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.

grep command is built-in on OS X and Linux. On Windows you'll have to install it; for example via [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html).

Comment: This will interpret entries in file2.txt as regular expressions. If file2 happens to contain e.g. `.*`, this doesn't work.

Comment: True. Thanks. Corrected by adding -F.

Comment: Still not a safe way to do it.  That will match substrings.  If file2.txt has the word 'a' in it, then all lines from file1.txt which have the character 'a' in them will be tossed.

Comment: The questions says: “How would I take all phrases on the lines of file2.txt away from file1.txt”. Substring match is fine then.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are huge (but must also be sorted), `comm` may be preferable to the more general grep solution proposed by Ivan since it operates line by line and thus, would not need to load the entirety of file2.txt into memory (or search it for each line).

```
comm -3 file1-sorted.txt file2-sorted.txt | sed 's/^\t//'
```

The `sed` command is needed to remove a leading tab inserted by `comm`.